# Friedberg linear algebra Theorem 6.30 proof

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

[image]

I have a question about Theorem 6.30 of Linear algebra (4ed) by Friedberg.
It is just a one equality that I highlighted in the picture. I can understand first two equalities but I cannot for third one. In contrast to proof of (a), b is not in range of T since the system of linear equations is inconsistent.

So, why projection of b on R(T) is unchanged here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the continuation of the sentence I gather that the third equality is just a typo and should be deleted.

Comment: Thank you, I think so, too :) But I posted this question to confirm that I'm right because this is nowhere in errata list. @DánielG.